# MySQL Selecting table that has the most columns?

Tags: mysql

```
select t.table_name from information_schema.tables t
left join information_schema.columns c
on c.table_name = t.table_name
and c.table_schema = t.table_schema
where t.table_schema = 'test'
and count(c.column_name) = max(count(c.column_name))
```

I am trying to select the table that has the highest amount of columns from the database "test."  However, I am unable to do this.  I have tried to select count(c.column_name) as well, but instead of returning the column count for each table, it just returns the maximum column count.

How can I select the table that has the most columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try grouping by table name.  Something like:

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME, COUNT(*) as c
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
GROUP BY TABLE_NAME
ORDER BY c desc
LIMIT 1;
```

[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/012fd/2)

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
select table_name, col_count
from
(
    select t.table_name, count(c.column_name) as col_count
    from information_schema.tables t
    left join information_schema.columns c
    on c.table_name = t.table_name
    and c.table_schema = t.table_schema
    where t.table_schema = 'test'
    group by t.table_name
) r
order by col_count desc
```

Answer (score 1):

Kind of repeating Mike's answer but I would also add database name:

```
SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME, COUNT(TABLE_NAME) AS C 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
GROUP BY TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME
ORDER BY C DESC
LIMIT 0, 1
```